# Need to fix Windows MBR without using a CD

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, mbr

I have a laptop which was Linux/Windows 7 dual-boot. I need to get rid of the Linux partition so that it only boots into windows.

I know how to do this if I have the Windows 7 CD(which I do). But this laptop does not come with a CD drive.

Is there anyway to do this without using the CD?

Answer (score 4):

Do the following

1. Start a cmd shell running as administrator (Start / Search / cmd / right-click Run as Administrator)
2. Type `bcdboot c:\windows`

That will re-write the MBR and so remove grub and re-install the Windows loader.

Comment: Is it possible to run bcdboot from linux or using vm ...

Answer (score 2):

A very easy solution would be to download and install [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net).

The tool comes with "Dual-boot Repair" utility. Run it and click "Automatic Repair". 
Confirm.

That's it ! You can reboot to Windows 7.

**Explanation:** The automatic dual-boot repair will (re)create Windows 7 MBR and PBR (master and partition boot record) and reset/repair the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store to default values (e.g. timeout 30 sec., Windows 7 as default loader).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

[How to create a bootable Windows 7 USB/DVD](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2009/12/-the-usb-flash-drive.ars)

No CD but always a USB

If this option is not good trying looking into any other USB booting ways.

That's the only way ... MBR cannot be fixed while it's active.

Comment: Making a bootable USB flash storage is good idea but it is **not only way**.

Comment: @Kamae... I'm sorry but I answer to the Original Poster... His case... he doesn't have a CD ROM drive so the only possible way is to do it with a flash drive... The other option would be to plug in a CD drive... So it comes to the same... Find me an other way and I will accept that you put minus -1 to my answer... Don't just minus my answer for now "apparent" reason... The answer is for the original poster not for general answer...

Comment: @Kamae... It would be nice when you "flag" an answer... To actually explain properly WHY... Since Windows 7.. Like Paul Said a bit higher here the BCDBoot.exe is a new thing from Windows 7 that let's you re-write the MBR ... Nice blog about it : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchingMyWindows7BootDiskFromDToCWithBCDBootRatherThanBCDEdit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a bootable flash drive with the Windows Recovery Disk installed to it. [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html) has a nice write-up on what you need to do.  If you have another computer with a DVD drive, that'll make it easier to create the flash drive, otherwise you'll have to download a torrent of the image. In either case, a second computer with Windows 7 already installed is necessary.