# Need to fix Windows MBR without using a CD

Tags: windows, linux, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to fix Windows MBR without using a CD](https://superuser.com/questions/367043/need-to-fix-windows-mbr-without-using-a-cd)

I have a laptop which was Linux/Windows 7 dual-boot. I need to get rid of the Linux partition so that it only boots into windows.

I know how to do this if I have the Windows 7 CD(which I do). But this laptop does not come with a CD drive.

Is there anyway to do this without using the CD?

Answer (score 3):

Boot the computer from a USB stick (which it supports unless it's more than 10 years old) that you can make very very easily by:

1. Downloading the [MS Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool).
2. Downloading an ISO of the Windows 7 version which you are already the owner of (official links [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/)).
3. Running the tool and pointing it at the ISO and the USB stick.

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know how it goes!